# How do I fix text that has been replaced by shaded blocks in Google Maps in Chromium?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, text, font

When I use Chromium Version 54.0.2840.59 (64-bit) with Google Maps, text does not appear correctly. The text may appear briefly, but then it is replaced by shaded blocks and nothing is legible. I expect no shaded blocks to appear and text to display in these spaces. This is on an OpenSUSE 13.2 OS. 
[image: Text fails to display]

This problem appeared after a software update in the last few weeks. I do not remember exactly what was updated in the OS, but I know there was an update to Chromium.

Google Maps text displays normally in Firefox 49.0.2, so the problem is specific to the Chromium + Google Maps combination.

What is the problem with displaying text correctly? How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by a Chromium update to version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit).