# Google maps not showing any names

Tags: google-maps

[image]

I am using google maps in chrome having OS: Ubuntu on my hp laptop. But it's not showing place names. I don't know how names have disappeared. Please help me to get them back

Comment: What version of the browser? Someone here recently reported a similar issue and it was solved be a browser upgrade. Try a different browser, too.

Comment: Related: [How do I fix text that has been replaced by shaded blocks in Google Maps in Chromium?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100116/354)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by installing stable version of chrome browser. I removed older chrome and then installed fresh one